# ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression | User defined function

Tags: oracle, function, group-by

I have the following query which uses a user defined function. Due to using `listagg`, I have to use the `group by` but I think it is failing in remote DB because of the user defined function:

```
    select p.player_code, 
           team_name,
           listagg(case 
                       when player_type = 'Def' and player_status in ('Fit', 'Mid-Fit') 
                       then player_group_name
                       else null 
                   end, ', ') within group (order by player_group_name) ctg, 
           schema_name.get_player_type_code@db_link(player_type, 'c')
    from schema_name.team@db_link t
    join schema_name.player@db_link p on t.team_id = p.player_team_id
    left join(select distinct player_id, player_group_name
              from schema_name.player@db_link i 
              join schema_name.player_sel@db_link ps on i.player_id = ps.player_sel_player_id
              join schema_name.player_queue@db_link pq on ps.player_sel_queue_id = pq.queue_id 
              join schema_name.player_queue_group pqg on pq.queue_id = pqg.player_queue_group_queue_id
              join schema_name.player_group pg on pqg.player_queue_group_group_id = player_group_id) ctg on p.player_id = ctg.player_id
    group by p.player_code, 
             team_name, 
             schema_name.get_player_type_code@db_link(player_type, 'c');
```

This query works fine in my main DB (without using the db link). However, it is giving me the following error when I run it in my remote DB (with using DB link): 
`ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`

If i remove the function (which exists in the main DB and the remote DB has the right privileges to execute this function. I can execute the function from remote DB without issues) from my query, it will work fine in the remote DB. But when I put it back in the query, it displays the same error.

Thoughts?

Comment: *"Thoughts?"* ->  `group by p.player_code`  ?   `select p.player_code` ?     not clear what you want or need see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)...

Comment: I have edited my question a little to what I think the issue is which is using `listagg` requires a `group by` clause.

Comment: i would suggest into providing a example data and expected results .. The GROUP BY usage in the query is plain wrong.. Oracle database should also except `SELECT 
 (SELECT
    player_inner.player_code)
  FROM
   player player_inner
  WHERE
   player_inner.player_id = p.player_id
  ) player_code, team_name,
           listagg(case ... ...
GROUP BY 
 player.player_id`   but without seeing example data and expected result i am not sure if this is what you need..

Comment: @RaymondNijland why use `MAX|MIN`? The only reason I am using the `group by` is because of using the `listagg` function.

Comment: i already editted the comment before you posted your comment It was indeed a error

Comment: As RaymondNijland already hinted, your select and group-by clause do not match - you are selecting `p.player_code` but grouping by`p.player_id`; suggesting this doesn't work locally in anything like the form shown, and is nothing to do with the function call. (It's feasible that's a typo in posting, and you're hitting a bug; but it doesn't look like it...). A [mre] that shows a working query and exactly what you execute might clarify things.

Comment: @RaymondNijland @Alex Poole, my mistake, I am grouping by `p.player_code` and that's why it is working properly in the main DB.

Comment: i assume this question is solved?  Consider accepting mine answer...

Comment: @RaymondNijland, Not really, I initially had it write, just a typo on the query. Problem still occurs when trying to run the query in the remote DB, still getting the same error.

Comment: remove `schema_name.get_player_type_code@db_link(player_type, 'c')` and check on the remoteDB if it works?

Comment: There are some known bugs in this area - 21120297 for instance - which *may* be related. The version of your local and remote DBs might be relevant. Check on MoS or with Oracle support for something more concrete, once you're sure you've ruled out other typo-level errors.